# random number generator returning a number not generated before

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I want a random generator that does not generate any numbers generated before. Calling this generator does not return a list. It returns 1 number every time and the number will be a totally new number not generated before.

My idea of implementing this so far is to generate a long non-repeating random list first and then retrieve from the list one by one.

Using Python, but I guess this is more of a general logic question.

edit:
Sorry for the confusion everyone. Clarification on the problem I am trying to implement: I am developing an app where a user can sign up and receive a hotel room number. The app has some hotels setup. Each new user will receive a unique hotel number of the hotel. The range will probably be from 0001 to 9999. My goal of this is to have an algorithm spit out a random number from 0001 to 9999 for that user, and this number has to be unique so that each room number of a hotel is occupied by one user only. I am using Django.

Comment: Can you give an example of a sequence you might expect to see?

Comment: *My idea of implementing this so far is to generate a long non-repeating random list first and then retrieve from the list one by one.* That is a good idea, what was the problem with it?

Comment: You've posted no code and no question.  Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You're a bit short on specification, and you've posted no attempt at all.  Stack Overflow is not a design resource; what's wrong with your implementation?  Post it with a specified problem, and we have something to work with.

Comment: It’s fine to ask about an algorithm for a problem even with no implementation (what would an “attempt” look like in that case?), but you do have to say that that’s your question.

Comment: If it is non-repeating then it is not random.  I would suggest an encryption.  Encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... to get a series of unique results up to the block size of the cypher you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the numbers you need to select from,

```
import random
x = [4,3,6,7,2,...]  # list of desired numbers
result = x.pop(random.randint(0, len(x) - 1))
```

Comment: You provide the list of desired numbers which should be unique, hence desired.

Comment: `x` is a list of unique values, you  pick one of them from random and then pop it from the list. I'm sorry how does the question of same number being picked again arise?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
import numpy as np
random_nums = []
for _ in range(10):
   while True:
       x = np.random.randint(0,10)
       if x not in random_nums:
           random_nums.append(x)
           break
```

Comment: This could be quite slow for the last few numbers.

Comment: Yes" If it was my code I would create a list using `np.arange()` and then shuffle it, but he didn't give much information about what he wants and this is a more "general" solution.